# how to get first word after phrase with regex

Tags: regex

How do you find the first word after a string literal via regex?

I.e.
I want to extract "DAQJ7PS" from the line:

> ERROR service.PostService  - Failed to save post DAQJ7PS

Answer (score 3):

```
/ERROR service\.PostService - Failed to save post (.+)/
```

will give you the result in the first capturing group. This can be tuned if you have more specific requirements.

Comment: `/post (.+)$/` would work too.

Comment: this extracts: "post DAQJ7PS" rather than the desired "DAQJ7PS".

Comment: @jopaki - What does `extracts` mean? Do you have access to capture buffers? If you do, whats wrong with reading whats in capture buffer 1? What flavor regex? If you use perl you could do this `ERROR service.PostService - Failed to save post \K.+`, if you just have lookbehind assertions, you could do this `(?<=ERROR service.PostService - Failed to save post ).+`, both of which are slower than reading capture buffer 1 in `ERROR service.PostService - Failed to save post (.+)`